Error 0xC02020C5: Data Conversion Failed During Import in SQL Server Management Studio
I'm trying to import a large CSV file (about 1,000,000 rows) into SQL Server using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). The file contains hospital charges, and one of the columns, AveragePayment, is a numeric field that should be imported as DECIMAL(18,2) in my destination table.
The import starts successfully and processes most of the rows, but around row 600,000, I encounter the following error:

Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "AveragePayment" (46) to column "AveragePayment" (116). The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."
(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[AveragePayment]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[AveragePayment]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion 0 - 0" (72) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input".

I have checked the AveragePayment column in the CSV file, and it appears to contain numeric values with two decimal places. Here are some steps I've already tried, but the error still occurs:
Checked the Data Type of the Destination Table:
The AveragePayment column in the destination table is defined as DECIMAL(18,2).
Checked the Source Data:
I verified that there are no non-numeric values, and all values have two or fewer decimal places.
Replaced any blank or NULL values with 0.
Despite these steps, I'm still getting the same error.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could suggest any other potential solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

seems difficult to tell you what's wrong in this row without actually seeing it. As a general advice I would look if some text column contain the separator that is not escaped properly / escaping not understood by ssms. e.g. : freetext, number : "this is a freetext containg, a, comma, separator, ", 12.345

open the file in excel and see the least/highest values

*.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are too long or missing completely, i.e. column positions will vary.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, encoding, and enforce data quality.

I would

right click on the data flow component
click on Show Advanced Editor
then navigate to the Input and Output Properties,
Check the column data type and length for your particular column matches between External columns and Input columns.

Sometimes SSIS holds the initial length even when the data type and length from your connection is fine.
Sorry, the edit came after the above proposed try. If it's direct import then l would keep the destination table with varchar columns (stage table), then have another table to hold the desired data types and do the conversion from the stage table into the table with decimal for the particular column
Hope this helps

Though this is tagged with [[tag:ssis]], the OP isn't actually using SSIS, they are using the Import/Export wizard, so the OP can't see the data flow task; they would; need to save the Task and then open it in an SSIS project to be able to do this.

If not using SSIS and trying to do a direct load, the most used solution is a staging table with varchar columns to avoid such errors, then do data conversions and cleaning as you get to a cleaner table within SSMS with the intended column data type. Decimal in this case
